# Emails rule in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, email-filter, rules

Good morning,

I'm struggling to set up some rules in my outlook and couldn't achieve what I'd like to automate. Basically, I'd like to set 3 folders:

Inbox: Only keeps email where there is ONLY MY NAME in the TO box. It includes emails only addressed to me, as well as emails addressed to me where other are in the CC or BCC box.

To Clarify: Emails where my name as well as other names are in the To Box

CC Box: All emails where my name is in the CC box and not in the to box

My issue is that I don't find a way to keep in my inbox the emails where only my name is in the TO box, doesn't matter if only addressed to me or if other are CC, as long as there is only my name in the to box.

Does anyone else has face same issue and find a solution?

Here are my current rules:

1- Apply this rule after the message arrives:
Sent only to me
except if it is an automatic reply
Stop processing more rules

2- Apply this rule after the message arrives:
Where my name is in the To Box
except if it is an automatic reply
Stop processing more rules

3- Apply this rule after the message arrives:
Where my name is not in the to box
Move it to the CC Folder

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Outlook rules doesn’t have such a condition(only your name in the To field) when creating rules.

But I found this can be done via search folder.

1)  Click Folder > New Search Folder.
2)  Select “Create a custom Search Folder” and click “Choose”
3)  Click “Criterria”
4)  In the option “Where I am”, select what you want.

[image]

You can still use current rules and add this search folder to show emails which only have your name in the “To” field.

Comment: thank you very much, it is a very good idea!!

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is that I don't find a way to keep in my inbox the emails where only my name is in the TO box, doesn't matter if only addressed to me or if other are CC, as long as there is only my name in the to box.

All emails which do not match your rules will remain in your `inbox`.  That is what your inbox is for.

If you want emails which only have you in the `To:` field to be separated, why not set up a folder for that?  Maybe `To Me Only Others cc`?

Then your first rule

> Apply this rule after the message arrives: Sent only to me except if it is an automatic reply Stop processing more rules

could be set to move those emails into `To Me Only Others cc` folder.